# auto checkin/out

Tags: iphone, android, google-app-engine, google-maps

I would like to develop an android/iphone app for automatic check-in/check-out based on the real time location updates. 
Let's say, At 7:00pm, 20 users are checked in a restaurant and 3 users left the restaurant at 7:01pm. My app should shows 17 users in the restaurant as of 7:01pm. My app should be able to update numbers of users in a place based on time interval..  Does Google API has check-in/out functionality ? If not, what kind of API I need to use ? Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my humble opinion, this is tough to achieve. I will state why. Because it is hard to accurately determine a location to the nearest meter such that you can accurately determine which place the user is in.

Added to that there is a time factor. The more accurate you want a location information the more time it consumes.

Lastly, there is a refresh issue here. Are you going to poll every minute to get the greatest and best location? This can be very expensive.

In my experience, none of the apps are that accurate, starting with google maps such that you can pinpoint the exact physical place per se. There will be errors.

You need
1. either the user to physically confirm his location
2. Have some installment in the physical location it self to acknowledge

I dont know..if there is a way I am all ears.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.  
Not to poll the greatest and the best location but I just want to see if how many users are in the places.. If you look at "trending" option in foursquare in android smartphone, it shows number of people are in the place. And I notice that the number keeps on changing, but I am not sure if the number of people just accumulates or fluctuates... 

Thanks !

Comment: How did you deduce from that they are auto-checked in or out. Folks manually checkin. and the app get that info from the server and displays it on the screen. It fluctuates because people are checking in and out from time to time

Comment: I didn't deduce that they are auto-checkedin/out.... Then there is some kind of function to check-out of the place in foursquare ? If it does, what kind of API I need to use to create something like that ? Does anyone know how did foursquare's checkin/out was built off of ? did they use google api ? thanks!

Comment: They built their own. Their API is also available for you to start from if you want. Simply put, they have list of users and places. when users click on check in button on the phone, some database table is updated with the checkin information. Other apps feed off the database tables and know if there are users checkin in the vicinity.

Comment: I think if they dont have checkout, following 2 happens: 1. User checks into a different location. At that point, they check him out from the first. 2. they run a process on their server to checkout people after a timeout. Say 3 hours or something.

Comment: I see you are a new user, if this answers your question please mark this answered. thanks.